# How to share a single segment of flash memory between two programs on an STM32 microcontroller

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, stm32

I'm writing an embedded program, which is divided in two parts: bootloader and app. (I'm targeting the STM32 and doing my development in C using the Eclipse IDE.)

I'm using a display, so I wrote some functions and 3 different fonts.
The idea is to use a sector of the microcontroller and share it.
The font area is defined with a linker (`ld`) script like so:

```
 .mySegment start_of_FONT_segm : {KEEP(*(.Courier_New_Bold_20_Section))}
 .mySegment1 0x8011298 : {KEEP(*(.Terminal6x8_Section))}
```

Then, I use an array to write in:

```
const unsigned char __attribute__((section (".Terminal6x8_Section"))) Terminal6x8[] = {
   0x00,
   0x00,
   ...
```

But how do I read it from another program (in this case, the application)?

I tried with:

```
unsigned char *Terminal6x8 = (volatile unsigned char*)0x08011298;
```

but the compiler puts the `Terminal6x8` into RAM.

I'll be glad to share some functions also, but I don't know how to declare those in `ld` and C syntax, either.

Comment: "but the compiler put the 'Terminal6x8'" Do you mean the pointer or the array also called `Terminal6x8`? Why did you give them the same name? The array likely needs to be declared at file scope so it can't have the same name as some pointer elsewhere.

Comment: The two definitions are in a different project. The first write into flash (with "section ..."), the other project just read, but the meaning is the same, so I call in the same way
Moreover, the two projects contain different #define, so I can use in code without think where they are.

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code:

```c
unsigned char *Terminal6x8 = (volatile unsigned char*)0x08011298;
```

is bad for many different reasons:

1. It uses a fixed (hard-coded) address, which is not very good.
2. It declares the data as `volatile`, which makes no sense in this context.
3. It does not declare the data as constant.

If you want the pointer to be also placed in the flash memory, you should write:

```c
const unsigned char * const Terminal6x8 = (const unsigned char * const) 0x08011298;
```

> I'll be glad to share some functions also, but don't know how to declare in ld and C syntax too.

The proper way to do it is to declare a vector table (*i.e.*, a table of pointers) containing the pointers to the data and the functions you want to share between the flash segments.

Comment: You're right, I forget to remove the "volatile" word. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the **pointer** *Terminal6x8 is put into RAM. If you want the pointer stored in flash, declare it const.

Although, the data pointed to by *Terminal6x8 is stored in flash at address 0x08011298 as you want. No matter where the **pointer** is stored.

Comment: I don't understand if the OP is referring to the pointer or the array, so the question can't really be answered without clarification. In case it's the array, it's likely related to yet another Eclipse linker fiasco and not trivial to answer.

Comment: Yeah. you are right, it could possibly be the array itself that OP refers to.
I didn't notice that he also called the array `Terminal6x8` as well. 
Clarification from OP is indeed needed.